# ISO Image for i686 Processor

Tags: dell

Can you tell me the link where I can find the ISO Image for the **Dell Latitude D410** with a **i686 processor**
Thanks and regards
Hermann

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1293143/edit) and add more information. Dell Latitude D410 is a computer. It does not fir inside an ISO image. Are you looking for a server or a desktop? You may find this question useful (See below)

Comment: That seems like a 32bit only CPU.  Lubuntu 18.04 32bit is the last ubuntu that will work for your computer and will be out of support next year(?).  Think you will have to try Debian or another Linux if you want longer term support.  Link for download.  https://lubuntu.net/lubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-released/

Comment: I used a `dell latitude d610 (pentium m, 1.5gb, intel i915)` for testing Lubuntu releases up to 19.04; however the only release still supported is Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.  You haven't mentioned how much RAM you have; mine had 1GB whilst it was used for testing 18.04/18.10/19.04 only subsequently upgraded to 1.5gb for 18.04.4/18.04.5; and the mount of RAM dictates the ISO you need to use which can be see at https://lubuntu.me/downloads/   Note: I tested Xubuntu 18.04 LTS too only that laptop (along with soem other *flavors*)

Comment: Note @crip659 you've pasted a non-Ubuntu / non-Lubuntu site; official release notes can be read at https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/  (adjust for the earlier point releases, or initial 18.04 release which had the *alternate* ISO (https://lubuntu.me/bionic-released/ for low ram boxes that can't run *live* and `ubiquity` at the same time; ie. <768MB)

Comment: Also note:   I didn't have issues with the d610, but two older thinkpads (used in *QA-testing*) with older pentium M cpus required the use of `forcepae --forcepae` to boot.  This is a CPU flaw that requires it (fixed in later pentium M cpus) so if you need to use it, use that option to make the ISO boot. Refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/AdvancedMethods or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE

Comment: @guiverc  Thanks, was not sure which one was which.

Comment: To add to the rest, [here is a Wikipedia list of lightweight Linux distros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_Linux_distribution) for you to consider.